# Open execl sheet using xlrd but it shows xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute '_IterParseIterator

Tags: python, xlrd

Hello i am trying to open excel sheet using xlrd .
But it was shows AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute '_IterParseIterator'.

```
import xlrd
sheet=xlrd.open_workbook('sheet.xlsx')
print(sheet)
```

Comment: Check the output of `dir(xml.etree.ElementTree)`, see if it has `_IterParseIterator`. I believe you won't find `_IterParseIterator`.

Comment: how overcome from this error

Comment: Let me try the same thing. what's your python and xlrd version?

Comment: xlrd is latest and python 3.7

Comment: For me it's working fine. I'm using ubuntu 18 and you?

Comment: is the issue resolved?